# How TO Avoid '=' 'or'

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

i make PHP site 
With USER / Pass Login 
But USer can Skip This Page BY Use
'=' 'or'
‘ or 1=1 
Like this 
Code Here In File Login_Check.php

`

```
include("includeszzz/host_conf.php");
include("includeszzz/mysql.lib.php");
$obj=new connect;
$obj1=new connect;
$username=$_GET["username"];
$password=$_GET["password"];
//echo $username;
//echo $password;
$sql="select username from  admin where username='$username'";
$obj->query($sql);
$U_num=$obj->num_rows();
//echo $U_num;
if($U_num!=0) {
$sql1="select password from admin where username='$username' and password='$password'";
$obj1->query($sql1);
$P_num=$obj1->num_rows();
    if($P_num!=0) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["zizo"]="$username";
    //header("location: welcome.php");
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "Invalid Password Please Try Again";
}
}  else {
echo "Invalid Username Please Try Again";
}
```

`

Comment: What you are experiencing is called [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Read the link I just posted and the one in @NathanTuggy's comment.

Answer (score 2):

You want to avoid using user data in queries without any type of sanitation.
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

"Example #5 A more secure way to compose a query..."

```
<?php

settype($offset, 'integer');
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM products ORDER BY name LIMIT 20 OFFSET $offset;";

// please note %d in the format string, using %s would be meaningless
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, name FROM products ORDER BY name LIMIT 20 OFFSET %d;",
                 $offset);

?>
```

- If the database layer doesn't support binding variables then quote
  each non numeric user supplied value that is passed to the database
  with the database-specific string escape function (e.g.
  mysql_real_escape_string(), sqlite_escape_string(), etc.). Generic
  functions like addslashes() are useful only in a very specific
  environment (e.g. MySQL in a single-byte character set with disabled
  NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES) so it is better to avoid them.
- Do not print out any database specific information, especially about
  the schema, by fair means or foul. See also Error Reporting and Error
  Handling and Logging Functions.
- You may use stored procedures and previously defined cursors to
  abstract data access so that users do not directly access tables or
  views, but this solution has another impacts.

Additionally, you can make use of Binding Parameters:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```